# Can I redo/undo in ipython shell?

Tags: python, shell, ipython

A feature in bpython called rewind.

Is there some similar key bindings?

Comment: this should be posted at http://superuser.com/ Good luck.

Comment: Disagree. This is a great question for SO, it's short and succint. Clearly meets FAQ guidelines. The question is so short and concise, in fact, that it's a bigger waste of time that anyone bothered to put comments about why it doesn't belong here than to just have the question as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: no.

bpython's rewind works, behind the scenes, by rerunning everything you've entered minus the last bit. It's a neat feature, but it's not all that important when you can just delete or replace any variable at any time.

If you do want to rerun all but the last line, you can use `%reset`, then `%rerun 1-17` (if you'd run 18 lines before).